# Download a page - Synchronously, not Async

Tags: download, actionscript-2

I'm new to AS2 and I saw there are functions to post data asynchronously: Send and SendAndLoad. However, they have unpredictable behavior when executed since they are async, and can finish after or before other functions.

But it doesn't matter if my script blocks to wait for a download.

Thus, I'm searching for a way to synchronously download a webpage in AS2 to a string.

Comment: So embarrassing to read after 4 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading data in a synchronous fashion would result in your Flash movie 'locking up' whilst it downloads the external data - which isn't really what you want to happen.  It would be far better to construct your code in such a way that it loaded the data Asynchronously, and then start a synchronous action afterwards.

I don't think a synchronous loading process like you're after is really possible, so it could be a case of reworking your code.  Can you provide a code example?

Comment: It's weird that async download is easier to implement than a sync download. Anyway, what I wanted to accomplish is similar to a 'Uploadstring' in .Net, and the data is 1k or 2k large, so it wouldn't lock for a long time. And the real reason I'm not confortable with an async call is because I'm not an AS2 coder so I don't understand why already defined stuff that I put inside my  post 'Success' callback are seen as undefined.